# Como faço para adicionar um valor a um vector de struct, por exemplo em algum campo do vector, pois ele é de uma struct

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


struct dados {
    int pessoas;
    int consumo;
};

int main()
{



    int totalx=0, totaly=0;
    int n,x,y;
     vector<dados> info;
    //int cidade = 1;
    cout << "Insira valor para N: ";
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin>> x;
        info[i].consumo.push_back(x); // como  add um valor para o campo do vector, pois ele é do tipo 'dados',uma struct ? 
    }





return 0;
}
```

Comment: O campo `consumo` é do tipo `int`. O que seria esse método `push_back`?

Comment: Como já dito pelo @AndersonCarlosWoss, você está a fazer confusão com os campos. O `push_back` não pode ser feito sobre um `int` como está a fazer mas sim sobre sobre o `vector` que é o seu `info`

Comment: então eu deveria fazer algo como  info[i].consumo = x ?

Answer (score 2):

Existe alguns equívocos em seu código, que provavelmente vem do seu conhecimento sobre *arrays*. O contêiner `std::vector` cresce e diminui de forma dinâmica, diferentemente de *arrays*, que têm um tamanho fixo e o espaço de armazenamento pra cada elemento já existe. Com `std::vector`, o espaço de armazenamento dos elementos é alocado conforme elementos são inseridos. Portanto, você não pode acessar um elemento sem que ele exista em um objeto `std::vector`. Por exemplo, o **código a seguir mostra esse equívoco**:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v[0] = 42; // errado
```

Se `v` fosse apenas uma *array* do tipo `int[N]`, não existiria problema algum em acessar o elemento 0 (claro, assumindo que `0 < N`). Como `v` é um objeto do tipo `std::vector<int>`, que foi inicializado por padrão (*default initialization* em Inglês), então ele não contém elementos, ou seja, está **vazio**.

Pra podermos acessar algum elemento, precisamos antes inseri-lo. Como você já deve ter descoberto, a função membro `std::vector::push_back` faz exatamente isso: insere um elemento no fim do vetor, corretamente alocando espaço o suficiente pro novo elemento. Também existe a função membro `std::vector::emplace_back` (desde [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)), que insere um novo elemento passando os argumentos passados pra ela pro construtor do tipo do elemento. Enfim, o pedaço de código de exemplo acima ficaria correto da seguinte forma:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(42); // ok
int i = v[0]; // também ok: elemento na posição 0 existe.
```

Não tenho certeza de que entendi a sua intenção em seu código, mas acredito que isto consertaria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> x;
    info.push_back(dados{0, x});
}
```

Se adicionarmos um construtor em `dados` que inicie seus membros, podemos aproveitar a função `emplace_back` (pois ela constrói o elemento no lugar chamando o construtor):

```
struct dados {
    int pessoas;
    int consumo;
    dados(int pessoas, int consumo)
        : pessoas(pessoas)
        , consumo(consumo) {}
};

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> x;
    info.emplace_back(0, x); // passa-se apenas os argumentos pra construir o novo elemento.
}
```